# Android debug bridge does not return anything in commands with python

Tags: adb

I'm doing some tests with android debug bridge in python(adb) and at the moment as a test I'm using Bluestacks 5 version 5.4.50.1009, I've been trying the code below and I just get nothing

---

from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient

client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5605);
print(client.version())

and the code doesn't work for me

Comment: did get any error message? is client.version() empty?

Comment: make sure adb-server is running on your account. You have to execute at least one time `adb` on command-line to start adb server.

Comment: I run the code and it just doesn't return anything, the process just keeps running and does nothing